# Can I use transport layer security(Https) with wsHttpBinding in windows service or console application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, binding

I want to use wsHttpBinding with transport level security(Https) for my WCF application. I know that I can achieve it by deploying my application in IIS but can I do the same things in the windows or console application and how can I achieve this

Comment: You should be able to.  IIS is a hosting option for WCF.  So are console apps and Windows services - the actual transport protocol used is under the purview of the WCF service via the binding, not the hosting option.  You should be able to find quite a few links and articles on how to do it both here on SO and through your favorite internet search engine.

Comment: Hi Tim. It will be of great help if you share some useful link with me as I searched it many times but I didn't get any good link yet

Comment: This is a mixed bag of results, but you can look at some of these: [WCF https windows service](http://www.bing.com/search?q=WCF+https+windows+service&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=wcf+https+windows+service&sc=3-16&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=5c410932cc5545b4a2761e8087e466e1)

Comment: Hi. Can anyone help me some specific link for using https in wsHttp